# 2-DRange -> Array -> 2D-Range with UDF Excel 2007 VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, resize, range, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a UDF that has 2D-Range as the input, resizes it, adjusts one of its values and has new 2D-Range as output. It is important to have Range as output since ranges will be used it other functions. Unfortunately other function do not recognize new 2D-Range as Range.

---

```
Function Func1(Structure As Range) As Variant

i = 3
Dim temp1 As Range
Dim temp2 As Range
Set temp1 = Structure.Resize(i, 3)

Dim arr1()
ReDim arr1(1 To i, 1 To 3)
arr1 = temp1
arr1(2, 2) = 100

Func1 = arr1

End Function
```

---

```
Function Func2(InputArray)

Func2 = InputArray.Rows.Count

End Function
```

---

So - function Func2(Func1(Structure)) does not work. it should give out number of rows in new 2D-Range.

Will anyone help please?

I'm using Excel 2007

Comment: You can't create a Range from scratch: you can only refer to an existing range. So, a function can't output a "new" range, it can only modify the input range, or output a reference to a different range in another location.

Comment: Tim, STRUCTURE is a 2D-range on a spreadsheet, and Func1 should change old range and output new one. Then I use Func2 to count number of rows in new range (and more complex functions as well) to work with new range. Originally I referred to old range (Structure) with Func2 to get number of rows, i.e. Func2(Structure). But now I need to modify original range, therefore I use Func1.

Comment: Another comment may be needed. I do not want to paste new range into spreadsheet. Rather would I refer to original range to get value of Func2, i.e. Func2(Func1(Structure)) as above.

Comment: `Func1` returns ARRAY not Range. What will you need to do with that ARRAY later- only check the number of elements like you're trying to do in `Func2` or anything more?? To return number of elements use in `Funct2` the following structure: `Func2 = Ubound(InputArray, 1)`

Comment: KazJaw, yes, this Func2 = Ubound(InputArray, 1) returns number of elements. But this is the simplest function. What I'm trying to do is the following. I had range called STRUCTURE, then I used Func2(STRUCTURE) to calculate various things. Now I need modified STRUCTURE (truncated and with changed elements) - therefore I use Func1. Ideally I need to get formula like Func2(Func1(Structure)). Theoretically this function should output number of rows in new range.

Comment: If you need to change `Range(STRUCTURED)` with some function and than return results/values into (almost) the same `Range(modif_STRUCTURED)` you will not do that with `Function` but with `Sub`. If you want to return results into another/new cells area `Range(newSTRUCTURED)` you will need to do it as you do with 'array-function'- using 'CTRL+Shift+Enter'. If you need some more help please extend your example, show another problem of possible `Func2`.

Comment: Yeah you're missing a step. See <http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx> especially the Application.Transpose(Arr) bits.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams and KazJaw are correct, you might consider using another approach. However, I have a possible solution and the code is below. Note that this approach will be slow and you must be strict with your exception handling.

```
Option Explicit

Function Func1(Structure As Range) As Range
    Dim TempWs As Worksheet 'Needed to create a range
    Dim temp1 As Range      'Resized input range
    Dim temp2 As Range      'Why is this needed?
    Dim arr1 As Range       'Range to be returned
    Dim i As Integer        '?

    'Add a temporary worksheet to the end
    Set TempWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(, _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    i = 3

    Set temp1 = Structure.Resize(i, 3)

    With TempWs

        'Set the temporary range and get the existing values
        Set arr1 = TempWs.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(i, 3))
    End With

    arr1.Value = temp1.Value

    arr1(2, 2) = 100

    Set Func1 = arr1

    'clean up
    Set temp1 = Nothing
    Set temp2 = Nothing
    Set arr1 = Nothing
    Set TempWs = Nothing

End Function


Sub test()
    Dim GetRange As Range
    Set GetRange = Func1(Range("A1:C3"))
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D1:F3").Value = GetRange.Value

    'You need to delete the temporary worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    GetRange.Worksheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set GetRange = Nothing
End Sub
```